# Sql query to udpate a column

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I pulled the values in the above table by joining 2 tables ROL_PRMSSN & ROL_MSTR. I then added the column ROL_DSC_REVISED for the revised values in excel.  I need to update ROL_DSC to the values in column D (ROL_DSC_REVISED). The PRMSSN_NM comes from ROL_PRMSSN table and ROL_NM and ROL_DSC come from ROL_MSTR table. Not sure how to write the query for it.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I am using ORacle sql

Comment: Are you saying that the value of column ROL_DSC, in the first row of the sample data, needs to be changed from _update a record_ to _update access_?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the join is irrelevant to your question. Are you simply asking for code to change the values from 'update a record' to 'update access', and so forth? That seems really straight forward, like

```
update table ROL_PRMSSN set ROL_DSC='update access'   where ROL_DSC='update a record';
update table ROL_PRMSSN set ROL_DSC='delete a record' where ROL_DSC='delete access';
etc
```

If it is more complicated, please update your question to add details. I feel like I am missing something important, but I'm not sure what it is.